# Changing the upper limit on PFQueries to something above 1000

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-server

Since the Parse libraries are now open sourced, I'm assuming there is a way to up the PFQuery limits from 1000 to something higher. I know how to run the queries recursively and then by resorting the tables and such to pull in more data using the 1K limit to then potentially pull in 10K or more, but I assume there is a way where I can change those hard limits in the SDK on the server side and iOS side. Is there is reason why this limit is set and would it be a bad idea to tweak this limit to something like 2K or so.

Any thoughts on this would be great. I understand that increasing this limit would require more processing time, but I want to know if it's possible anyway and what the ramifications are. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can easily do this. As example you can inherit from the PFQuery object and override the limit value.

```
var Parse = require('parse');

class MyQuery extends Parse.Query {
  constructor(obj) {
    super(obj);
    this.limit(10000);
  }
}
```

This code is in Javascript for the server side, but you can do the same in Swift like that

```
class MyQuery: PFQuery {
    init(className: String, predicate: String) {
        super.init(className: className, predicate: predicate)
        self.limit = 10000
    }
}
```

I hope this solve your problem